# Unindo várias queries SQL em uma query só

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho uma 'missão' em meu trabalho, onde preciso unir algumas queries em uma query só. Porém não faço a menor ideia de como posso fazer isso para que tudo que eu preciso seja retornado usando apenas uma consulta ao banco. Existe alguma maneira de unir as consultas? UNION não resolve o problema pois as tabelas e os dados são diferentes.

Por exemplo, unir essa query:

```
SELECT b.natureza, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM tabela1 a
LEFT JOIN tabela2 b ON (a.servico = b.cod)
WHERE b.cod notnull AND
a.status = 0 AND a.data_mov BETWEEN 77770 AND 77810
Group by b.natureza
order by 1
```

... com essa query:

```
SELECT tag FROM tabela3 WHERE cod = 1
```

... e com mais essa:

```
SELECT seq 
FROM tabela1 a
LEFT JOIN tabela2 b ON (a.servico = b.cod)
WHERE b.cod NOTNULL AND b.natureza = QN:Nat AND 
a.status = 0 AND a.data_mov BETWEEN 77770 AND 77810
ORDER BY 1
```

de forma que todos os resultados sejam exibidos numa tabela só.

Comment: Estas tabela não possuem campos que as liguem? Vi que você já está usando joins então como, por exemplo, uma tag vai se relacionar com uma natureza, ou com o seq?

Comment: Tu pode colocar um exemplo de como os dados devem ser exibidos?

Comment: Os dados devem ser colocados dentro de uma Array, para que eu possa usá-los depois. A ideia de unir as queries é minimizar o acesso ao BD. Algumas das tabelas não se relacionam entre si, porém são necessárias para que eu possa receber os dados.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solução "ingênua"

Dá para usar UNION, desde que mantenha os campos iguais, deixando os não usados vazios.

Exemplo:

```sql
SELECT b.natureza as natureza, COUNT(*) AS total, '' as tag, '' as seq
FROM tabela1 a
LEFT JOIN tabela2 b ON (a.servico = b.cod)
WHERE b.cod notnull AND
a.status = 0 AND a.data_mov BETWEEN 77770 AND 77810
Group by b.natureza
order by 1

UNION

SELECT '' as natureza, '' as total, tag, '' as seq FROM tabela3 WHERE cod = 1

UNION

SELECT '' as natureza, '' as total, '' as tag, seq 
FROM tabela1 a
LEFT JOIN tabela2 b ON (a.servico = b.cod)
WHERE b.cod NOTNULL AND b.natureza = QN:Nat AND 
a.status = 0 AND a.data_mov BETWEEN 77770 AND 77810
ORDER BY 1
```

## Esta é a melhor solução?

Não, é uma gambiarra. Executar 3 queries em uma não deixa a conexão com o banco mais rápida. Na verdade o banco vai executar as 3 queries normalmente e pode ainda ter um *overhead* de memória.

O que geralmente deixa a execução de várias queries lentas é não usar corretamente os objetos de *statements* e conexões com o banco de dados. Trabalhei em um sistema Java que retirava conexões do *pool* e as fechava para cada consulta. Alteramos o sistema para recuperar uma única conexão por requisição e o ganho de desempenho foi na ordem de 300%.

Mesmo que haja algum ganho mínimo com essa "união" em determinadas situações, para mim isso cai na categoria de micro-otimização, isto é, algo muito específico que resolve um problema em particular, mas deixa o código mais propenso a erros e de mais difícil manutenção.

Uma solução mais adequada que geralmente pode ser feita é colocar certas informações em *cache*. Essa `tag` recuperada não poderia ser armazenada em memória? Se as alterações não forem frequentes isso vai trazer um bom ganho de desempenho. Só não se pode esquecer de invalidar o cache quando a tabela ou o registro forem alterados.

## Alternativa para consulta dentro de laço

Para *queries* executadas dentro de um *loop*, é possível usar técnicas de cache no código em questão.

Vou colocar um exemplo fictício, mas ilustrando o princípio:

```js
mapaCache = { }
queryPrincipal = execute('select * from tabela_principal')
for (dados in queryPrincipal) {

    //recupera o código de algum lugar
    codigoTag = 1 

    //verifica se a tag já foi carregada
    tag = mapaCache[codigoTag]

    //se não tem ainda, carrega do banco e salva no cache
    if (tag == null) {
        tag = execute('select tag from tabela3')
        mapaCache[codigoTag] = tag
    }

    //coloca os dados no array

}
```

Se você já souber o(s) código(s) a serem pesquisados com antecedência, basta colocar as queries que se repetem fora do loop. Exemplo:

```js
tag = execute('select tag from tabela3')
queryPrincipal = execute('select * from tabela_principal')
for (dados in queryPrincipal) {

    //coloca os dados no array

}
```

## Join ou Subquery

Outra alternativa seria fazer *join* entre as tabelas ou colocar em uma *subquery*.

Antes de mais nada, não entendi porque não dá para recuperar `seq` já na primeira *query*.

Além disso, não sei qual o relacionamento da `tabela3` com as demais, mas se tiver algum você poderia fazer uma *subquery* , assim:

```sql
SELECT b.natureza, COUNT(*) AS total, 
    (SELECT tag FROM tabela3 WHERE cod = tabela1.codigo_tag) as tag
FROM tabela1 a
LEFT JOIN tabela2 b ON (a.servico = b.cod)
WHERE b.cod notnull AND
a.status = 0 AND a.data_mov BETWEEN 77770 AND 77810
Group by b.natureza
order by 1
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou testar em breve. A ideia por trás de fazer uma única consulta é que o código que faz acesso ao BD tem um loop que consulta o BD toda vez que é executado, sendo assim, se o loop é executado 100 vezes, ele faz 100 acessos ao banco para retirar um único dado. A ideia é otimizar isso e eu não sabia por onde começar.

Comment: @gh0st_h4wk Nesses casos, você pode extrair a parte que se repete para fora do loop e armazenar os valores num mapa, por exemplo. Outra solução é usar um mapa dentro do loop. Vou atualizar a resposta com um exemplo em pseudo-código.

Comment: @gh0st_h4wk Dê uma olhada na atualização da resposta, principalmente no tópico final.

Comment: Obrigado, estava lendo já. Seguinte: a primeira query retorna a natureza de um documento e a quantidade dos mesmos. A segunda query retorna uma tag associada à essa natureza (a natureza é um inteiro e a tag é uma string) enquanto a terceira retorna uma sequência numérica referente  a cada item de cada natureza. Porém, ainda existem outras queries no código que eu preciso otimizar, usei essas como exemplo apenas para tentar entender se seria possível juntá-las.

Comment: @gh0st_h4wk Certo. Eu creio que é possível juntar na maioria dos casos com *joins* e *subselects*, alguns casos com *cache*. Se você tiver muitas queries, sugiro criar um modelo do banco de dados para entender melhor o relacionamento entre cada tabela e assim facilitar a refatoração das consultas.

Comment: Isso vai ser complicado, pois o banco tem 27 tabelas. Mas vou tentar ver o que posso fazer! Obrigado!